# Both Dockerize and be able to debug a Django app using vscode

Tags: django, docker, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to both Dockerize a Django app and still be able to debug it using Visual Studio Code's debugging tool? If yes, how? E.g, using docker-compose to run Django app, postgres, and a redis instance and be able to debug the Django app via Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Can you use Docker for the PostgreSQL and Redis dependencies, but a host-based Python for actual development work?  That might be easier to set up; it won't have special IDE dependencies, and you can directly access the Python interpreter and any associated tools normally.

Comment: Actually I will have 2 micro apps besides PostgreSQL and Redis, one is a Django app for REST API and another is a Python app to do some asynchronous stuff and update Django app state (read posts and update them possibly using Django REST framework). This is my use case. And I thought i can orchestrate them together using docker-compose and they can access each other internally. Do you think my approach is valid? If so, how to implement do your suggestion? You mean hosting the Django app on a simple server separately?

Comment: That actually sounds like an easy architecture to run this way: you should be able to get away with running the worker by hand as you need to run an individual task.  They probably wouldn't access each other _directly_; work-queue systems like Celery will generally use an intermediate store like Redis to store the actual jobs.  You can _deploy_ all of this using a single Compose file even if you _develop_ it using local tools.

Comment: Thanks. You're right. I forgot to supplement a separate worker to the architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.

I've done it with a NestJs app and should be a similar setup.

Expose a specific port on the Django app service in the compose file first.

Create the launch.json file the following configuration, then replace `<port-exposed-on-container>` and `<directory-on-container>` with real values.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": 
    [
      {
        "name": "Docker: Attach to Node",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "port": <port-exposed-on-container>,
        "address": "localhost",
        "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "remoteRoot": "/<directory-on-container>",
        "protocol": "inspector",
        "restart": true
      },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for Django apps. Even the "address" property is not allowed when the "type" is "node"